# What is the correct way in OpenCL to concatenate results of work-groups?

Tags: opencl

Suppose that in an OpenCL kernel, each work-group outputs unknown amount of data. Is there any efficient way to align that output on the global memory so that there are no holes in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method might be to use [atomic_add()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_add.html) to acquire an index into an array, once you know how large a chunk your workgroup requires. In OpenCL 1.0, this type of operation required an extension ([cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics.html)). These operations may be very slow, possibly going as far as locking the whole global memory bus (whose latency we tend to avoid like the plague), so you probably don't want to use it on a per item basis. A downside to this scheme is that you don't know the order your results will be stored, as workgroups can (and will) execute out of order.

Another approach is to simply not store the data contiguously, but allocate enough for each workgroup. Once they finish, you can run a second batch of work to rearrange the data as required (most likely into a second buffer, as memmove-like tricks don't parallellize easily). If you're passing the data back to CPU, feel free to just run all clEnqueueReadBuffer calls in one batch before waiting for them to complete. A command queue with CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE might help a bit; you can use the cl_event arguments to specify dependencies when they occur.

Comment: Thanks! It is a shame that `atomic_add()` is slow, it is a great logical solution. In that case, I don't understand the second solution. Yes, I can allocate enough for each workgroup, no problems. So, suppose I know a work group never outputs more than 4 values. In the end, I will have a global buffer like that: result = [x,x,x,\_, x,\_,\_,\_, x,x,x,\_, x,x,x,x, x,\_,\_,\_, ...], where each `x` is a result value. Did I follow you well? If so, what I don't get is how I get rid of the holes (and it is necessary, because I will refeed `result` into a new kernel).

Comment: The way that comes to mind is: Store the size of each group output in another array. Then process that array to create a list of which result group goes where (just accumulate the sizes to create offsets), and run a parallel copy to compact the data.

Comment: Ah, I get it, thanks for the clarification! Great solution, I will be using it.